# azure blob storage allow more than one connection while downloading

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Blob Storage to upload files. 
I am trying to download files from Azure by using **WebClient**:

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
 {
     client.Proxy = null;
     client.DownloadFile(url, fileNameAndPath);
 }
```

My question is this: Azure allows only one connection for download and it is really slow. Is there a way to allow more than one connection for download in Azure Blob?

Comment: you want to download `multiple file over one connection?` or `one file per connection?`

Comment: i want to download one file

Comment: Azure doesn't limit you to one connection, nor does it limit you to serial upload/download. In your sample, you're using a non-Azure method (`WebClient.DownloadFile()`), treating your blob like any other streamable URL. You should try a blob-specific method, such as `DownloadToFileAsync()`, which knows about block blobs and can move multiple blocks in parallel.

Comment: I am aware of blob-specific methods. But I must use `WebClient.DownloadFile()` for security reasons. I am working on a thin-client project.

Comment: @emert117 - then I think you've answered your own question. The limitation is not with Azure in this case. However, "really slow" is vague & subjective. There might be ways of speeding this up (e.g. changing the type of blob storage you're using to make sure it's the latest type with higher throughput).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DavidMakogon . I know  "really slow" is vague, but believe me it is slow. Maybe there is a setting in Azure Blob Portal for allowing  more than one connection. What I need is downloading Azure Blob Storage files without blob-specific methods.

Comment: There's no such setting. Blob storage is a massive service (storage-as-a-service). There is no notion of single-connection.